# div moves incorrectly on browser resize

Tags: css, html, resize

I'm trying to set-up a shopping cart for my site, and I lack some knowledge in correctly using css to format the three columns when the browser is resized.

The css originally had the following:

```
.threeFrames .leftStyle {float: left; position: relative; width: 20%;}
.threeFrames .centerStyle   {float: left; position: relative; max-width: 60%;}
.threeFrames .rightStyle    {float: left; position: relative; width: 20%;}
```

But this didn't have the effect I wanted. I want to set the two end columns to fixed `width 240px` however, when I do this, when the browser is resized, it bumps the right hand column below the others, whereas I want just the middle column to shrink.

Comment: margin / padding? + as for me `.rightStyle` should be `float:right` & `.centerStyle` with no floating.....

Comment: you should [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+3-column) before asking

Answer (score 1):

If you make `.rightStyle {float:right;}` and don't style the middle column at all, it will automatically wrap around when possible.